# login ошибка 419 TokenMismatch

Tags: laravel

Если открыть форму авторизации и оставить на некоторое время, то при вводе логина и пароля с последующей попыткой залогинится вылетает 419 ошибка. Время простоя до выпадания ошибки разное и непонятно от чего зависит.
Испробовано:
 1. Обновление токене ajax-запросами через промежуток времени
 2. Обновление токена перед отправкой формы

Answer (score 0):

Возможны сбои в стореджах.

повесьте их обнуление на кнопку отправки формы:
localStorage.clear();
sessionStorage.clear();